# is posible manipulate mediastream directly without canvas api?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediastream, mediadevices

I'm created a simple video-chat using javascript and WebRTC for do connection between users client i want to add posibility that users can use some custom filters like video effects and other related stuff, 
i found some examples and are useful but all examples do modification using canvas api I mean the video-stream is proccesed then drawed in a canvas next reproccess for be sent as MediaStream obtained from it
i felt that all this step are redundant and i want to know if exists some way to manipulate video stream directically avoiding the use of canvas api ?

Comment: [You can capture the canvas to a MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream).

Answer (score 1):

[WebRTC-NV](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-nv-use-cases/#funnyhats*) lists some use-cases related to that (such as background blurring) but there are no implementations yet so you'll have to go via canvas+captureStream.